# Julia: How to change the type of an argument in the Bessel function?

Tags: julia

Here is my code:

```
using Plots
using SpecialFunctions
using QuadGK

kappa = 1
B = 1
xi = (kappa/B)^4

function correlation(x)
    quadgk(q -> q * SpecialFunctions.besselj0(x*q)/(q^4 + xi), 0, 1e6)[1]/kappa 
end

r = range(-20, 20, length = 1001)

plot(r, correlation(r))
```

I get an error on the Bessel function. I get that the argument is the problem and that it should be of the format `::BigFloat`, `::Float16`, or `::Float32`, but I don't know how to do it. I tried to write `x .* q` instead, but the problem remains the same, I get the error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching besselj0(::StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}})
```

Also, I'm searching for a way to write +infinity instead of `1e6`.

Comment: The answer to the second question is probably `Inf`, <strike>but I don't know whether QuadGK accepts that as integration boundary.</strike> [Appearently, it does](https://juliamath.github.io/QuadGK.jl/stable/#QuadGK.quadgk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `correlation(r)` with `correlation.(r)` in your code to use broadcasting, as is explained [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#man-dot-operators).

The core of your problem that in Julia functions are not broadcastable by default - you usually have to opt-in to have it (especially when you work with numerical code). Here is a basic example:

```
julia> sin(1)
0.8414709848078965

julia> sin([1])
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching sin(::Array{Int64,1})
Closest candidates are:
  sin(::BigFloat) at mpfr.jl:727
  sin(::Missing) at math.jl:1197
  sin(::Complex{Float16}) at math.jl:1145
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[2]:1

julia> sin.([1])
1-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.8414709848078965
```

However, in your case the `correlation` function is quite expensive. In such a case I usually use ProgressMeter.jl to monitor the progress of the computations (it shows how long you can expect for the computations to finish). So you can write:

```
using ProgressMeter
result = @showprogress map(correlation, r)
```

and use the `map` function to apply `correlation` function to all elements of `r` (in this case the result will be the same as for broadcasting).

Finally, your computations will be much faster if you do not use global variables in `quadgk`. It is better to pass `kappa` and `xi` as arguments to the function like this:

```
function correlation(x, kappa, xi)
    quadgk(q -> q * SpecialFunctions.besselj0(x*q)/(q^4 + xi), 0, 1e6)[1]/kappa 
end

result = @showprogress map(x -> correlation(x, kappa, xi), r)
```